# Can't get filesize when reading file over HTTP wrapper

Tags: php, filesize

My attempt to get filesize of remote file, accessible via HTTP, using PHP's [wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) has failed.

To be 100% sure, let me state, that:

- file exists,
- [`ini_get('allow_url_fopen')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php) returns `1`,
- [`stream_get_wrappers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-wrappers.php) returns `http` on the list and
- [`var_dump(fopen($filename))`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) returns `resource(119) of type (stream)`.

Which all means, that remote file is accessible. And yet, I'm getting:

```
file_exists($filename): bool(false)
is_file($filename): bool(false)
is_writable($filename): bool(false)
is_readable($filename): bool(false)
```

And the attempt of calling `filesize($filename)` ends with `filesize(): stat failed for...` error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found in PHP's docs for [HTTP/HTTPS protocol wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php). The "[Options](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php#refsect1-wrappers.http-options)" section explains, that though this protocol allows reading, it does not support [`stat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) function.

Thus, [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) works like a charm, while [`filesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) and other functions, that require `stat()` to work, fails for this wrapper. Notice, that PHP documentations says, that these functions supports only ***some*** URL wrappers:

> As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with some URL wrappers. [Refer to Supported Protocols](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) and Wrappers to determine which wrappers support [stat()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) family of functionality.

Seems, that HTTP/HTTPS wrapper is not among them.

You may try to use `fopen()`, which works with this wrapper, to implement very own version of file size determining function. But, since `fopen()` actually opens file (while `filesize()` reads file size from the file system / meta data), this would be a really overkill in any scenario, I can think of. And... `Allowed memory size of XXX bytes exhausted (tried to allocate YYY bytes) in...` will be your closest friend for the evening.